# Detect Server Start Signalr Websockets C#

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr

Im writing a web-application with websockets that updates datatables in realtime. It works great for those clients that starts their browsers after I start my C# written "signalr websocket server". But those that starts their browsers before I start my server never connects. Anyone have an Idea how to do this? Do I have to have something like a manual "connect" button?

/Staffan Mattsson

Answer (score 0):

You could have a manual re-connect button, or you could simply keep re-trying the connection until the server is available. Something like:

```
 var timer = setInterval(function() {
         //Try connecting every 5 seconds
     }, 5000);
```

Then once you have a successful connection, use `clearInterval(timer)` to stop trying to reconnect.

SignalR will attempt to automatically reconnect on its own, but only if it was able to make a successful connection in the first place.

Comment: Im so sorry I havent tried any of the two solutions already mentioned here. Someting other came up in the project. I will still test this later :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find very usefull informations about connections in signalr here :

[handling-connection-lifetime-events](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#continuousreconnect)

You ll find a way to continuously reconnect :

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $.connection.hub.start();
   }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
});
```